# How to create kind of heatmap in Excel or Tableau

Tags: excel, tableau-api

How to create below mentioned "chart image" in Excel or in Tableau from such data table "Table Image"? Not sure if that "chart image" is heatmap or something different.

Table Image

[image]

chart image

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure looks like a heatmap to me. Although the 'resolution' on your table vs. your picture are very different--lot more records in the image you've shown.

https://hevodata.com/learn/tableau-heatmap/